# Error when adding my custom syscall to kernel

Tags: c, shell, unix, linux-kernel, kernel

So i've been adding my custom syscall to kernel. This is my syscall's source code:

```
//sys_procmem.c. This syscall helps users to show the memory layout of a specific process.
#include <linux/linkage.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
struct proc_segs {
    unsigned long my_id;
    unsigned long start_code;
    unsigned long end_code;
    unsigned long start_data;
    unsigned long end_data;
    unsigned long start_heap;
    unsigned long end_heap;
    unsigned long start_stack;
};
asmlinkage long sys_procmem( int pid, struct proc_segs * info) {
    struct task_struct *task;
    info->my_id = 1512853;
    for_each_process(task){
        if((int) task->pid==pid){
                info->start_code=task->mm->start_code;
                info->end_code=task->mm->end_code;
                info->start_data=task->mm->start_data;
                info->end_data=task->mm->end_data;
                info->start_heap=task->mm->start_brk;
                info->end_heap=task->mm->brk;
                info->start_stack=task->mm->start_stack;
                return 0;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Everything seems fine until when i write a testing program after i compile my kernel, source code:

```
//sys.c
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define SIZE 100
int main() {
      long sysvalue;
      unsigned long info[SIZE];
      sysvalue = syscall([number_32], 1, info)
      printf("My ID: %lu\n", info[0]);
}
```

I compiled the program with:

```
gcc sys.c -o sys
```

Then i ran it with:

```
./sys
```

I got this error:

[image: Error]

Please help me, thank you guys for reading :)

Comment: Have you carried out [these](https://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/) steps?